# Maximum value of field of vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, vector-layer, maximum

If I have a vector layer in QGIS, how do I use Python to find the maximum value which a given field has?

I need to convert the values in one field into values between `0` and `1`. I guess I therefore need to set it to `val/maxVal`. That's why I need to find the maximum value.

Comment: and what if I'd like to evaluate the maximum for each unique value?
This doesn't work at all...could someone find the error? thanks uniquevalues=layer.uniqueValues(index,limit=10000) for uv in uniquevalues: features = layer.getFeatures() for feat in features: values = [] attrs = feat.attributes() values.append(attrs[field]) if feat[field] == uv: maxarea = max(values)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not necessary to get a complete list of field values. In **QgsVectorLayer** exists 'maximumValue' method. So, this works well and it's shorter:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('fieldName')
print layer.maximumValue(idx)
```

Comment: Just a note - the biggest advantage of using QgsVectorLayer.maximumValue over iterating through every value is that maximumValue can hand calculation of the maximum over to the data source itself. Ie, for a Postgres layer QGIS will send a simple "select max("field") from ..." query to the database, rather then having to fetch every single feature from the database and iterate through them. It's a dramatic performance win.

Comment: Not working on string columns. Code proposed by Joseph fix te issue.

Comment: Notice that the precision seems limited, I have a few dozen points with a field set at 438.56, and the result is 438.57. Using layer.maximumValue(layer.fields().indexFromName('field_alt')), QGIS 3.22, Win 10 Pro.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer does not work in QGIS3.

Now one has to do:

```
fieldname='id'
layer=iface.activeLayer()
idx=layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname)
print(layer.maximumValue(idx))
```

(I am setting fieldname as the first line to make it easier to cut and paste for someone wanting to test it with their layer)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following in the **Python Console** to print out the maximum value for a given field:

```
values = []
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('fieldName')
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    values.append(attrs[idx])

print max(values)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to get a complete list of field values. In **QgsVectorLayer** exists 'maximumValue' method.

Comment: Also works, but @xunilk's is the better solution.

Comment: @TomChadwin - Can't argue there =)

Answer (score 1):

There are also several other approaches available:

### Approach 1 : [`QgsAggregateCalculator`](https://qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsAggregateCalculator.html#a51eb9f5752cf107d72266829a21cf2fa) with `Max`

> Available aggregates to calculate.
>
> Not all aggregates are available for all field types.

This approach is available since QGIS 2.16.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
max_value = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Max, "name_of_your_field")[0]
print(max_value)
```

### Approach 2 : [`QgsVectorLayerUtils`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayerUtils.html#module-QgsVectorLayerUtils)

> Contains utility methods for working with QgsVectorLayers.

This approach is available since QGIS 3.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
max_value = max(QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues(layer, "name_of_your_field")[0])
print(max_value)
```

### Approach 3 : [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#module-QgsVectorLayer) class with [`getFeatures()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures) method

Similar to @Joseph's solution

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
max_value = max([feat["name_of_your_field"] for feat in layer.getFeatures()])
print(max_value)
```